# How are bugs detected?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, security

I was wondering how bugs in iOS, Android, Facebook, etc detected. Is there a specific pattern one may go about detecting them? I am asking about bugs in operating systems and also websites (including web applications). Is the process the same or different. If so, how?

Comment: this is not a topic for stackoverflow. try other stackexchange site ->  Programmers.

Comment: What is your position in this scenario? Are you the Developer? Project manager? Designer?

Answer (score 3):

Generally bugs are found through the QA or Dev process. Having a dedicated team or not, the process is essentially the same.

Run through all functionality of what you're testing - note any unexpected behavior. At a minimum, try to think of all possible scenarios, use cases, test cases, and if possible edge cases (things that aren't what you would expect the user to do, but theoretically could happen).

If there are no visible bugs, then looking at your backend may be required (if you store values for example, you should check these)

Comment: Agree. Every project passes from QA phase and that's where we mostly face bugs. In addition, big part of them comes from user reports and app tracking. After releasing your app you still keep watching crashes, problems and report that bugs.

Answer (score 0):

There are several stages that are gone through (at least by myself and I can imagine many others) to detect bugs in applications.

1. **REVIEW** -- Once it is written, comb through the code and check for any
   non-optimum situations that can be easily remedied. Don't try to
   re-invent the wheel here, just check for anything which can be
   swiftly and easily resolved.
2. **PERFORMANCE** -- Performance testing is key. Run your application and check what it
   takes to run. How much CPU is it using? How much should it be using?
3. **MEMORY** -- Watch your memory usage. Memory usage can become one of the greatest problems if leaks or zombies exist. check to make sure that all of your memory is being allocated and deallocated properly and that there is no wastage. A small increase of memory over a 1 minute period could mean a crash in a few hours.
4. **UI TESTING** -- UI Testing is the next crucial step. Now that you are satisfied that you application runs and performs well, what will the user see? Is it slow to respond? Do transitions and animation flow? Does it feel natural? does it look nice? Play with your app and use every function available to see that it works nicely.
5. **IDIOT TESTING** -- Idiot testing. No joke. You will get some users who are below average on the user intelligence scale and you will be surprised to see some of the bugs that they come up with. So go through the UI testing again, but this time be dumb. Do strange things that a normal user wouldn't normally do. **TRY TO CRASH THE PROGRAM**. Break the "rules" and go hog wild. you might find some surprising bugs.
6. **BETA** -- Beta release. That is the biggest tool used in testing. Select a few users from many and give it to them to use. See what happens and request that they turn in feedback. Survey them and find out what they do and do not like. Based off of their feedback, change or ignore as you like.

These are the steps that I usually take before releasing an app or program.

Another tip, if you are developing, is isolating the source of the crash. It might seem obvious, but sometimes even I forget to do it. If I notice a bug, I don't just kill the bug. I find where the bug came from, how it got there and I kill the reason it came into existence. That way, no other bugs can result. You might also find that the source of one bug was actually the cause of many others.